# MODx Evo: How to assign a predefined placeholders to a template?

Tags: php, api, modx-evolution

I load the HTML Header of every page from one common snippet. There are different types of Templates eg. Website or Blog Article. There can be a number of different templates Templates for Articles as well as Websites, though. So I would like to add to every Template some kind of a constant to it which populates a placeholder in the HTML Header, which would look like this:

```
<meta property="og:type" content="[*myplaceholder*]" />
```

and would create depending on the "constant" assigned to the template for instance

```
<meta property="og:type" content="website" />
```

or

```
<meta property="og:type" content="article" />
```

.

I try to avoid using the regular setup of template variables. I could do that and use the ManaerManager to manipulate and hide those. But I am actually looking for a cleaner solution. May be just in PHP.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I do a replace like this with my modules inside templates using PHP (this is greatly simplified, and I'm not using MODx Evo...). First I search in the file for the replacement characters and then do a simple replace:

```
<?php
if ( strstr($current_content, '[*myplaceholder*]') !== false ) {
   $replaced_content = str_replace('[*myplaceholder*]', 'website', $current_content);
}
?>
```

What you replace it with will depend on what you're trying to do, but hopefully you get the general idea.

Comment: MODx comes with a a cool template and template variable system and i would like to hook into this. I use similar technique as yours when i write plugins for it, which pulls snippets with placeholders. But may be i can go somewhere in that direction. i have to think about if that will work.